# How to read a file containg just 1 line or 1 word in Java

Tags: java, file

I have a file, I know that file will always contain only one word.
So what should be the most efficient way to read this file ?

Do i have to create input stream reader for small files also **OR** Is there any other options available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Scanner

```
File file = new File("filename");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
System.out.println(sc.next()); //it will give you the first word
```

if you have int,float...as first word you can use corresponding function like nextInt(),nextFloat()...etc.

Answer (score 3):

Well *something's* got to convert bytes to characters.

Personally I'd suggest using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) which will allow you to write something like this:

```
String text = Files.toString(new File("..."), Charsets.UTF_8);
```

Obviously Guava contains *much* more than just this. It wouldn't be worth it for this single method, but it's positive treasure trove of utility classes. Guava and [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) are two libraries I couldn't do without :)

Answer (score 0):

Efficient you mean performance-wise or code simplicity (lazy programmer)?

If it is the second, then nothing I know beats:
`String fileContent = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString("/your/file/name.txt")`

Comment: I am of-course a lazy programmer ;-)
But what about its performance ???
Which one is better .. Scanner or this one or buffered reader ?

Comment: When working with files the performance bottleneck is the IO performance of the machine, not the code. BufferedReader can help a little over regular IO streams, but who's to say Scanner doesn't use a BR under water?

Answer (score 0):

**-** Use `InputStream` and `Scanner` for reading the file.

**Eg:**

```
public class Pass {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        File f = new File("E:\\karo.txt");
        Scanner scan;
        try {
            scan = new Scanner(f);


        while(scan.hasNextLine()){

            System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
        }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**-** `Guava` Library handles this beautifully and efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Use BufferedReader and FileReader classes. Only two lines of code will suffice to read one word/one line file.

```
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Demo.txt"));
    System.out.println(br.readLine());
```

Here is a small program to do so. Empty file will cause to print 'null' as output.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

 public class SmallFileReader
       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Demo.txt"));
            System.out.println(br.readLine());  
   }
 }
```